# How to grab the option class value based on the variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form>

    <select id="ammount">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option class="100" value="0"></option>
        <option class="200" value="5,01"></option>
        <option class="300" value="10,01"></option>
    </select>

    <input class="height" id="height" name="height" value="">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {

        $('form').on('change', '#height', function(){
            var height  = "3,00";

            // HERE I NEED TO GRAB THE RIGHT OPTION CLASS FROM SELECT OPTIONS
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is **how to find the right option and grab the class name**? The rule is that it should select the option row that is less than the height value (3,00) and the first next option row bigger than  height value (3,00).

So, in this case it would be `<option class="100" value="0"></option>`

But if the height would be `5,55` the right option row would be `<option class="200" value="5,01"></option>` and the same for `10,01`.

However, for height = "10,01" or more the right option row would be `<option class="300" value="10,01"></option>`

I was thinking that finding the first bigger value (5,01) and minus 1 row would be the right way to go, but I am not sure how to do that.

Remember that height could be any value (it's from an input box typed by a user) and the options are pulled from db dynamically.

Comment: You have no element in your form with id `height`.

Comment: @qwertynl Thanks, I have updated my code. Check it now, please.

Comment: are those commas  for `.` i.e. decimal

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

     $('form').on('change', '#height', function(){ 

        var height  = "3,00";

        var height_num = parseFloat(height.replace(',','.'));
        var selected_item_value;
        var heights = [];
        $('#ammount option').each(function(i, item){
            heights.push(item);
        });
        $(heights.reverse()).each(function(i, item){
            if (parseFloat($(item).val().replace(',','.')) < height_num) {
                 alert($(item).val())
                 selected_item_value = $(item).val();
                 return false;
            }
        });
         $('#ammount').val(selected_item_value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not wokring. COuld you try that in js fiddle or something to prove that it really works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: woops, forgot to used item.value instead of $(item).val()... should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<select id="amount">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option class="100" value="0">0</option>
    <option class="200" value="5,01">5,01</option>
    <option class="300" value="10,01">10,01</option>
</select>
<input class="height" id="height" name="height" value="55">
</form>
```

**script**

```
var t;

$('#height').focus(function () {

var that = $(this)

t = setInterval(function () {

    var height = parseFloat(that.val().replace(',', '.'))


    $('#amount').children('option').each(function () {

        var compareTo = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', '.'))

        var compareToNext = 0

        if ($(this).next().length > 0) 
          compareToNext =parseFloat($(this).next().val().replace(',', '.'))

        if (compareTo < height && height < compareToNext && !isNaN(height)) {
            $('#amount').val($(this).val())

        } 

        else if (compareTo < height && $(this).is(':last-child') && !isNaN(height)) {
            $('#amount').val($(this).val())
        } 

        else if (isNaN(height)) {
            $('#amount').val($('#amount').children('option:first').val())
        }



    }) //end of each
}, 500) //end of setInterval
})  //end of focus

$('#height').blur(function () {
    window.clearInterval(t)
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/qqcrx/)